# Oracle Apex - can't customize plug-in

Tags: oracle, plugins, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am currently working in the Sample Charts application in Oracle APEX version 5.1.2. I would like to edit the code for the Gantt Chart plug-in, but for some reason it won't let me type in the PL/SQL code box or erase anything in the box. I read somewhere online that only the master copy of the plug-in can be customized and that the Reference Master Plug-in From box has to be blank. However, it does say that "This is the "master" copy of this plug-in" and I can't erase or choose a blank value for the Reference Master Plug-in From box. In addition, on the screen that shows the list of all the plug-ins for the application, it says that this plug in was subscribed from a "Nonexistent Master".

This is what I am seeing on my screen:

[image]

[image]

Has anyone seen this before and/or know how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Popup LOV for "Reference Master Plug-in From" and pick "- no plug-in -" to break the subscription, after clicking "Apply Changes" you will be able to make the necessary modifications.